# What reaction happens when carboxylic acids are treated with calcium hydroxide and distilled?

Tags: acid-base, carbonyl-compounds, decomposition

What reaction takes place when $\ce{Ca(OH)2}$ reacts with $\ce{R-COOH}$? What is obtained after distillation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acetic acid (as an example of a typical carboxylic acid) reacts with calcium hydroxide to form calcium acetate. This is a simple acid-base reaction which forms a salt and water:

$$\ce{2CH3COOH + Ca(OH)2 -> (CH3COO)2Ca + 2H2O}$$

Upon heating, calcium acetate undergoes decomposition to acetone and calcium carbonate. The acetone can be distilled off from the mixture, leaving behind solid calcium carbonate:

$$\ce{(CH3COO)2Ca ->[\Delta] CaCO3 + (CH3)2C=O}$$

At even higher temperatures calcium carbonate itself can be decomposed to calcium oxide and carbon dioxide:

$$\ce{CaCO3 ->[\Delta] CaO + CO2}$$

**References**

1. http://www.docbrown.info/page04/OilProducts10.htm